# Try/Except error when using 'None'

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I have a bit of code that isn't behaving as expected. 
I've condensed it down to the problem here:

```
item = None

try:
    if item != None:
        print('pass')
except TypeError, e:
    print('fail')
```

if item is something other than 'None' type it prints pass. I wanted raise an exception 
if the item is None but when I set item to None nothing prints out.

I could easily do this with an if statement but I'm curious to know why this isn't working as an try/except.

any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to `raise` an error?

Comment: `item != None` should be `item is not None`. Read [Pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). From Pep8: _Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators._

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing to raise a `TypeError` in your `try` block, it simply checks whether `item !=None`. `item !=None` will be `True` or `False`, but won't raise an error in either case.

You could do the following:

```
item = None
try:
    if item != None: # better: if item is not None
        print('pass')
    else:        
        raise TypeError 
except TypeError:
    print('fail')
```

Or simply:

```
item = None
if item != None: # better: if item is not None
    print('pass')
else:
    print('fail')
```

Comment: When testing for `None`, always use `is None` or `is not None`. `None` is a singleton, after all.

Comment: Thanks Martjin, I tried to resemble the OP's code as close as possible, but will leave a comment to hint at the better way of writing it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I couldn't remember if it was best to use 'is/is not' with None.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to raise an exception when `item` is `None` the simplest way is

```
if item is None:
    raise TypeError("'None' value provided for item of farkling routine")
```

As already pointed out, in your example you weren't causing any exception for the `except` clause to trigger on. But I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic way:

```
item = None
result = 'pass' if item is not None else 'fail'
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original Code:

```
item = None

try:
    if item != None:
        print('pass')
except TypeError, e:
    print('fail')
```

The reason the `print('fail')` in your `except` does not work is due to the fact that no errors were actually raised by the try except block. Think about it, variable `item` was declared above so it does exist. Then you are testing to see `if item != None`, in this case it is None, however that would not raise an exception.

Lets remove the `item = None`, like so.

```
try:
    if item != None:
        print('pass')
except TypeError, e:
    print('fail')
```

You will find that your try except block will now raise an exception calling your `print('fail')`. This is because, now you are trying to test `if item != None`, but there is no such variable `item`, hence the exception call.

A simple way to check if a variable is `None` is to do something like this.

```
is_none = True if item is None else False
print(is_none)
```

which is equivalent to

```
if item is None:
    is_none = True
else:
    is_none = False

print(is_none)
```

Comment: Your `is_none = True if item is None else False` example is somewhat non-Pythonic, when the same result is achieved by `is_none = item is None`.

Comment: @holdenweb You are right. I don't know why I did it that way as I dont do it that way in my own code, probably to be a little more readable and show the use of inline if statement for future use.

Comment: Brains just fart sometimes :)